# Issue with active support when trying to install rspec - undefined method 'to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activesupport

I am trying to install RSpec to do some testing on an app that I did not write. I've placed

> gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.8"

in my gemfile and ran bundle install. This worked fine. Until I ran

> rails generate rspec:install

I get this error:

> /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in
>   `method_missing': undefined method`to_sym' for nil:NilClass
>   (NoMethodError)   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1309:in
>   `action_path'     from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1304:in`
>   path_for_action'     from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1159:in
>   `match'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1358:in`
>   match'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:394:in
>   `map_method'  from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:323:in`
>   get'     from
>   /Users/anthonyto/ActiveNetwork/active-trainer/config/routes.rb:447:in
>   `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:565:in`
>   block in controller'     from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:546:in
>   `scope'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:565:in`
>   controller'  from
>   /Users/anthonyto/ActiveNetwork/active-trainer/config/routes.rb:446:in
>   `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:624:in`
>   block in namespace'  from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:546:in
>   `scope'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:624:in`
>   namespace'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1119:in
>   `namespace'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/ActiveNetwork/active-trainer/config/routes.rb:406:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:624:in
>   `block in namespace'  from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:546:in`
>   scope'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:624:in
>   `namespace'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1119:in`
>   namespace'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/ActiveNetwork/active-trainer/config/routes.rb:405:in
>   `block in <top (required)>'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:239:in`
>   instance_exec'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:239:in
>   `draw'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/ActiveNetwork/active-trainer/config/routes.rb:1:in`
>   '    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in
>   `load'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`
>   block in load'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
>   `block in load_dependency'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in`
>   new_constants_in'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
>   `load_dependency'     from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`
>   load'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in
>   `block in reload_routes!'     from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in`
>   each'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in
>   `reload_routes!'  from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/application.rb:120:in`
>   block in routes_reloader'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in
>   `call'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in`
>   execute_if_updated'  from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in
>   `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:52:in`
>   call'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:52:in
>   `block in <module:Finisher>'  from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in`
>   instance_exec'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in
>   `run'     from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in`
>   block in run_initializers'   from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in
>   `each'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in`
>   run_initializers'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in
>   `initialize!'     from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in`
>   method_missing'  from
>   /Users/anthonyto/ActiveNetwork/active-trainer/config/environment.rb:5:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in`
>   require'     from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in
>   `block in require'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in`
>   block in load_dependency'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in
>   `new_constants_in'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in`
>   load_dependency'     from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in
>   `require'     from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in`
>   require_environment!'    from
>   /Users/anthonyto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from script/rails:7:in`require'    from
>   script/rails:7:in `'

I am running ruby version 1.9.3 and rails version 3.0.20. I can provide any additional information, any help would be very greatly appreciated. Thank you all!

EDIT: Turns out I am getting this same error when I try to start my rails server. Seems like there is a deeper issue with my app. I certainly did not have this issue before, and cannot think of anything I did that would've caused it.

Comment: Please post your fix as an answser for closure.

Comment: Looks like I have to wait another 5 hours to do so, because my reputation is not high enough. But will do, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FIX: So I figured out what was going on, i'll leave it here for anyone else that runs into this annoying error. Turns out I was being an idiot and left some faulty code in the routes.rb file that looked like this:

> ```
>   controller :calendar do
>     get #write some routes here
>   end
> ```

Commented that out, and everything worked fine.